# Changing the elasticsearch host in logstash 1.3.3 web interface

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I followed the steps in this [document](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/kibana/current/using-kibana-for-the-first-time.html) and I was able to do get some reports on the Shakespeare data.

I want to do the same thing with elastic search remotely installed.I tried configuring the "host" in config file but the queries still run on host as opposed to remote .This is my config file

```
input {

stdin{
  type => "stdin-type" }

file {
  type => "accessLog"
  path => [ "/Users/akushe/Downloads/requests.log" ]
 }
}

filter {
  grok { 
    match => ["message","%{COMMONAPACHELOG} (?:%{INT:responseTime}|-)"] 
  }
  kv {
    source => "request"
    field_split => "&?" 
  }
  if [lng] {
    kv {
     add_field => [ "location" , ["%{lng}","%{lat}"]]
    }  
  }else if [lon] {
   kv {
   add_field => [ "location" , ["%{lon}","%{lat}"]]
  }
 }   
}

output {

 elasticsearch {
   host => "slc-places-qa-es3001.slc.where.com"
   port => 9200
  }

}
```

Comment: Hello, what logstash web interface are you using?? I think you parsed the log and saved in remote es but viewed the local one.

Comment: I am starting it using the following command.I guess this is the standalone version
java -jar logstash-1.3.3-flatjar.jar agent -f logstash-complex.conf -- web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `protocol => http` in to make it use HTTP transport rather than joining the cluster using multicast.